# Parsing a raw string to select by expression

Tags: pyqgis-3

This works as expected:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
lyr.selectByExpression("\"fieldname\" > 0")
```

According to this [this article about parsing raw string in python](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string) the following lines of my code should work just the same but they don't.

```
query_dict = {"query1":r"\"fieldname\" > 0"}
lyr.selectByExpression(query_dict["query1"])
```

What am I missing out on?

Comment: I don't think that a raw string is what's needed here, you've specified a raw string but still escaped the chars: r"\"fieldname\" > 0" is the string *\"fieldname\" > 0* which isn't correct, remove the r and your string becomes  *"fieldname" > 0* which makes more sense.

Comment: It should also be legal to use `query_dict = {"query1":r'"fieldname" > 0'}` (single-quotes around the double-quote within the string)